# Google maps street view is grey (throws error b.hasAttribute is not a function)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, vuejs2

I have implemented (in VueJs 2) google maps with custom marker. So far everything works well as expected.

[image]

The problem I have is, when I drag street view guy on map and release it, my map becomes grey and I get following errors in dev tools

[image]

And this my code/method for google maps

```
showMap() {
    const initMap = gmapsInit();
    initMap.then((google) => {
        let myLatLng = {lat: this.latitude, lng: this.longitude};
        let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: myLatLng
        });

        let contentString = '<div id="content">' +
            '<div id="siteNotice">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + this.locationTranslations.name + '</h1>' +
            '<div id="bodyContent">' +
            '<p>' + this.description + '</p>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';

        let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

        let icon = {
            url: '/static/img/map-pin.svg',
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
        };

        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            icon: icon,
            map: map,
            title: this.locationTranslations.name
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        countryService.getClientLocation()
            .then((response) => {
                let locationCoordinates = response.data.loc.split(",");
                this.userLocation.lat = parseFloat(locationCoordinates[0]);
                this.userLocation.lng = parseFloat(locationCoordinates[1]);

                let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
                let directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                directionsService.route({
                    origin: myLatLng,
                    destination: this.userLocation,
                    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
                }, function (response, status) {
                    if (status === 'OK') {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    } else {
                        this.$snotify.warning(
                            'Please allow location tracking, so we can show you directions to location',
                            this.$t('warn')
                        );
                    }
                });

            })


    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
},
```

Can some one please help me out, what I'm missing or what I'm doing wrong, so my map will be able to display street view? If you need any additional informations, please let me know and I will provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have been affected by the version rollover of the Maps Javascript API,I would suggest that you use the version 3.34 as a workaround, you may do this by adding v parameter in you Maps Javascript API script tag, you may see the sample below:

```
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&v=3.34&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Please also note that this has been recognized in the Issue Tracker for Google Maps Platform, you may visit this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/125539051) to learn more about the issue.

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting and not place a single comment, how to fix this issue.

So far on this issue tracker it's specified following:
This is actually not a bug with the API, but an issue with your current implementation. You'll need to update your code to make sure that your implementation does not use a variable that is being used in the JS API, or reserved word in Ecmascript.

Do we have a list which variables we should not use?

Comment: also thank you for the workaround, but since 3.34 will be retires soon I will have to find some other solution for my problem